# Can a vampire's human child and another human make vampire babies?

Tags: the-sims-3

A vampire and human can have both vampire and human offspring. Can their human child have vampire babies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply put; No.

For occult status, only the parents are checked.

Of course, if the human child were to later become a vampire, their children would be able to inherit it. ;)